SAS dataset index copy
i have a sas dataset which is large in size(90+GB). To keep only recent data i created a new dataset where the latest data is present. now the older dataset has an composite index on it. Is there any way to point the index from older dataset to new one.
i couldn't figure out how to copy index

You will have to recreate the index whenever you recreate the dataset that only has the updated data. For example, suppose you have a compound index called "idx" on sashelp.pricedata. You can create the compound index at the same time you create the dataset:
data lib.latest(index=(idx=(regionName productLine)));
    set sashelp.pricedata;
    where date GE '01JAN2000'd;
run;

When you do it once, you can remove old data and append new data as needed without recreating the index. For example, you can use a modify statement to remove old values and proc append to add new values. You technically can do this all in one step, but you'll find better performance if you separate them.
data lib.latest;
    modify lib.latest;
    where date LE '01JAN2001'd;
    remove;
run;

proc append base=lib.latest data=new_data force;
run;


I don't think you can take an existing index and point it at a different dataset, and not sure it would make sense.  The index for the older dataset would have more rows than the new dataset.  I think you will need to build a new the index for your new dataset.
The other approach I guess would be to start from scratch.  You could copy your old data set and old index to make a new dataset and new index.  You can do this  with PROC COPY or PROC DATASETS, see e.g. https://support.sas.com/kb/24/810.html. Then in the new dataset you could delete records you don't want.  That would logically achieve the same thing, but my guess is easiest to just rebuild your index on the new dataset.
